# changes in commits are not shown any more

Tags: magit

when commiting in magit it used to open a diff window where I could see the changes I'm commiting right now. For some reason this window doesn't open any more on some repos. I must have disabled this behaviour somehow. Unfortunately I don't know how I did this or how to undo this.
Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have added something like the following to your configuration:

```
(remove-hook 'server-switch-hook 'magit-commit-diff)
```

Simply remove it and the diff popup should be shown again.

Note that you can show the diff manually with `C-c C-d` (`magit-diff-while-committing`).

Comment: Thanks the command works, but I haven't added something like this. I think I did this by closing the buffer or killing it.